# complex number geometry -1

Tags: geometry

Last night I was lying in bed looking at my ceiling, thinking about Decartes and his fly and the cartesian plane, and I was trying to visualize how you would find the square root of -1 on the caretsian plane. Is that even possible? Do complex numbers correspond to that type of cartesian geometry? Do they correspond to any geometry?

Specifically the square root of -1, can that be represented on the caresian plane?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ (the complex plane is isomorphic to the $2$-dimensional Cartesian plane). Indeed, we can imagine $\mathbb{C}$ as the following picture shows:

[image]
<sub>(source: [clarku.edu](http://www.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/complex/plane.gif))</sub>

To quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), which explains it very clearly, "[the] real part of a complex number represented by a displacement along the x-axis, and the imaginary part by a displacement along the y-axis".

Comment: but the square root of negative one is what I really want to know- can we visualize this one?!

Comment: @matthias.anglicus $$\sqrt{-1}=i$$ Find it on the picture above.